# Tracing log for user doing transaction

Tags: .net

I want all of you help to create file log for tracing user transaction. I want to do that when a user wants to update or add some information, I want to trace which information that user was updated.

The tracing file that I want is easy read and search. Even, it is in text file or xml file.

Thanks,
Sopolin

Comment: question as it stands makes little sense...

Answer (score 0):

[System.Diagnostics.TraceSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracesource.aspx) is a good place to start looking.